# 502 Error Nginx and uwsgi Ubuntu Server

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

Hi I am getting the following error and have been searching and searching for an answer for my situation.  I realize googling this issue has many solutions but ive tried them all and cant figure out why mine isnt working  below is my nginx.conf and a log of the error please let me know if more information in needed

Log

```
2014/08/18 20:03:36 [error] 27960#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://192.168.0.13:8081", host: "mysite.com"
2014/08/18 20:05:01 [error] 27960#0: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://192.168.0.13:8081", host: "mysite.com"
2014/08/18 20:08:19 [error] 28371#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:8001", host: "mysite.com"
2014/08/18 20:08:21 [error] 28371#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:8001", host: "mysite.com"
```

.conf

```
upstream django {

server 127.0.0.1:8001;
}



server {
  location / {
    include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass django;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that whatever port I set in my uwsgi.ini file "socket = :" has to match the port I put as the server port in

```
upstream django {

    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
}
```

Dont know if this is a true solution or whats actually going on behidn the scenes but it seemed to fix the issue